# Htc - I can't handle keyevent

Tags: android, htc-android

I have in  a screen an edit text. I want to do something button done . On google nexus s , samsung galaxy it works perfect. On keyboard the button appears with text "done". On htc the button does not appears it appear enter simbol. I ve tried to ad in code or clause to treat event enter but it does not respond

```
        edit1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    edit1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {

            if (arg1 == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                chercher.performClick();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance, 
Raluca

Comment: I believe this is a known issue with HTC Sense.

Comment: Can i test somehow in code if the phone is htc ? in this case i can show a dialog where i add a edit text and a button

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,  IME Actions are not consistant across device vendors. My advice would be to keep your listener and also make a provision in your design to have a button in case the listener doesn't fire.

Comment: after implementing a lot of "solutions" and have no result. I will add a button. The thing is that i want the button to be visible just if the phone is htc . can i test this in code?

Comment: THe build class has many constant that may provide the manufacturer but Im not sure if that a reliable way. Creating designs according to a vendor is a bad design especially when you cannot be sure you don't have same issue with some other vendor. It also makes the app UI inconsistant.